# How to increment a value in line conditioned by previous line in R?

Tags: r

I need to add 1 in lines with the same values, because I need different values. How can I do that in R? I tried the code below, but it didn't work!!

Example: I have

```
             name   value
             ADF    10
             ABG    10
             HFM    13
             SAB    36
             TCC    23
             BHG    20
             JKH    20
             DRE    12
             CFG    14
             CFC    18
             LKM    18
             POI    47
             TSE    21
             BBB    9
```

I need:

```
           ADF  10
           ABG  11
           HFM  13
           SAB  36
           TCC  23
           BHG  20
           JKH  21
           DRE  12
           CFG  14
           CFC  18
           LKM  19
           POI  47
         TSE    21
          BBB   9
```

I tried :

```
         i=1
       df$value2<-0
         for (i in nrow(df)) 
          {   
             t=i+1
             if (df$value[i]==df$value[t]) {df$value2[i]=df$value[t] + 1}
             if (df$value[i]!=df$value[t]) {df$value2[i]=df$value[i]}
            }
```

Comment: Preference of the second!

Comment: What happens if you have the same value repeated multiple times?  What happens if by adding one to a value you create repeated values (ie: 1, 1, 2 would be come 1, 2, 2).

Comment: I don't understand why you add 1. If you can change the values that much and it doesn't matter, why not simply assign arbitrary unique values, e.g., a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dat$value[c(FALSE, dat$value[-nrow(dat)] == dat$value[-1]) ] <- 
  dat$value[c(FALSE, dat$value[-nrow(dat)] == dat$value[-1]) ] +1

> dat
   name value
1   ADF    10
2   ABG    11
3   HFM    13
4   SAB    36
5   TCC    23
6   BHG    20
7   JKH    21
8   DRE    12
9   CFG    14
10  CFC    18
11  LKM    19
12  POI    47
13  TSE    21
14  BBB     9
```

This might be shorter with something like diff(x)==0. There's also an earlier [r] question about how to build an increment function that might be of interest.

```
dat$value[c(FALSE, diff(dat$value)==0) ] <- 
  dat$value[c(FALSE, diff(dat$value)==0 )] + 1
```